# Highlighting an element (or character) but actually copy a different word

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highlight

I wonder if it is possible to highlight an element or a word but it lets you copy a different word if you hit `ctrl+c`.

Let's say I have an element which is an emoji and it uses a sprite background:

Original text: `:heart:`
What my html outputs:

```
  <span background={...logic here}></span>
```

I wonder if it is possible that when the user highlighted the span he can actually copy the `:heart:`.

## Update:

I forgot to mention that there are other text beside the span so it could look like:

Text: `Hello world (emoji here) blablabla`

HTML:

```
<p>Hello world> <span background={...logic}></span> blablabla </p>
```

Comment: This might help you https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp

Comment: with javascript, anything like this is possible, but this is too broad and therefore off topic for SO

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to override a copy event.

[Reference here.](https://w3c.github.io/clipboard-apis/#override-copy)

In your logic, you'll want to check if what is copied is equal to the heart, and then replace it with what you want them to copy.

Comment: Hio, I'm not sure if it'll work if I have other text/ elements on my clipboard tho?

Comment: You should be able to handle this just fine. Say you have a sentence "hello world test" and you want to replace the word "test" with "it worked". When a copy event is fired, your handler should check to see if the string contains "test" and then you'll just replace "test" with "it worked" in the string. (there are numerous ways to implement this functionality, if you need more specifics let me know)